# How to register and use mongoose-deep-populate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

okay. so I'm trying to do some nested population of my `mongoose` models. And I found that `Mongoose-Deep-Populate` was one of the easiest fixes for the nested solution, however, as easy as it might seem, I can't figure out how to register the plugin correctly.

I'm using a `angular-fullstack` project and just added the `npm install` of the `deep-populate` plugin. And then I went into my model and added this:

```
'use strict';

var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EntrySchema = new Schema({
    articleId: Number,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    date: Date,
    children: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Entry'
    }],
    forum: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Forum'
    },
    language: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Language'
    },
    orphan: Boolean,
    writer: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    type: String
}).plugin(deepPopulate, options);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', EntrySchema);
```

As you can see it is possible to have multiple level of nested `entries` in my model. So to find them all I wrote this:

```
// Get list of chapter entries
exports.chapter = function(req, res) {
    Entry.find()
        .where('orphan').equals(true)
        .populate('children')
        .exec(function (err, entrys) {
            Entry.deepPopulate(docs, 'children', err, entrys) {
                if(err) { 
                    return handleError(res, err); 
                }

                return res.json(200, entrys);
            };
        });
};
```

However this doesn't work. And I'm quite sure I did something wrong. I've checked around the net, but doesn't seem to be able to find an example which can clarify my mistake. And I've now come to you my great masters for a solution to my troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
exports.chapter = function(req, res) {
  Entry.find()
      .where('orphan').equals(true)
      .populate('children')
      .exec(function (err, entrys) {
          mongoose.deepPopulate(entrys, 'children', err, function(err, entrys) {
              if(err) { 
                  return handleError(res, err); 
              }
              return res.json(200, entrys);
          });
      });
};
```

If you face any difficulty. Please let me know